# How to do that in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I know PHP and learning Javascript Now, I want to ask that how can I do the stuff here in this PHP code in Javascript?

```
PHP Code: 

$name = "Jhon Doe";
echo "The old name was $name";
$name[0] = "F";
echo "The new name is $name";
```

How to get the same result in Javascript?

```
JS => ?
```

Comment: JavaScript strings are immutable, so you cannot directly do that. You have to build a new string from parts of other strings.

Comment: Stack Overflow is *not* a code translation service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself** and then if you have a problem you can **post what you have tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [how to ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you try and make the title of the question a bit more specific to this problem as it's a bit too vague at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first couple of lines are trivial and would look like:

```
let name = "Jhon Doe"
document.write(`The old name was ${name}`)
```

`document.write()` being in place of `echo`, but one would not generally use document.write but instead output the string into a element like `document.getElementById('some-id').innerText = someVar` or simular in jquery `$('#some-id').text(someVar)`, vue `{{someVar}}`, handlebars `<%- someVar %>` etc etc but thats not what you asked.

The rest would need to use a function to either split up the string and replace that char, or use something like substr.

So when all is said and done your code would look like:

```
let name = "Jhon Doe"
document.write(`The old name was ${name}`)
name = `F${name.substr(1)}`
document.write(`The new name is ${name}`)
```

Hope it helps, defo check out some basic JS tutorials string manipulation and variables is very much first lesson.